# How To Run JS Function When Form Entry

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, web-scraping

I want to make a website where users will enter webflow website URL and then they will get code

JS Code // Using (npm install website-scraper)

then add the below code in magic.js (filename)

```
const websiteUrl = formvar; // formvar will be placed as url

scrape({
    urls: [websiteUrl],
    urlFilter: function(url) {
        return url.indexOf(websiteUrl) === 0;
    },
    recursive: true,
    maxDepth: 50,
    prettifyUrls: true,
    filenameGenerator: 'bySiteStructure',
    directory: './node-website'
}).then((data) => {
    console.log("Entire website succesfully downloaded");
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log("An error ocurred", err);
});
```

And to run this I need to use terminal

`node magic.js`

What I want is to make this done by one click of form submit

Comment: Index.html code is live at webcited.co

Comment: Are you looking to continue to do this server-side, as the node.js tag implies?  Is your current web server in node.js, using Express or something of that nature?